# NextJS giving error when conditionally redirecting using next-auth status

Tags: reactjs, next.js, next-auth

I am using NextAuth to authenticate a session. While doing so, I am trying to do the following:

In the auth pages,

- redirect `authenticated` status to '/'
- else show signin page

The code for the above is as follows:

```
// layout.js
export default function Layout({ children }) {
  const { status } = useSession();

  if (status === 'unauthenticated')
    return (
      <div>
        {children}
      </div>
    )

  if (status === 'authenticated')
    redirect('/', 'push');
}
```

This gives the following errors in browser:

```
Warning: Cannot update a component (`HotReload`) while rendering a different component (`Router`). To locate the bad setState() call inside `Router`, follow the stack trace as described in https://reactjs.org/link/setstate-in-render
```

```
Uncaught Error: Rendered more hooks than during the previous render.
```

```
The above error occurred in the <Router> component:

Router@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:148:93
ErrorBoundaryHandler@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:77:9
ErrorBoundary@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/error-boundary.js:104:53
AppRouter@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/app-router.js:396:47
ServerRoot@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:166:24
RSCComponent
ReactDevOverlay@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/components/react-dev-overlay/internal/ReactDevOverlay.js:66:9
Root@webpack-internal:///(app-pages-browser)/./node_modules/next/dist/client/app-index.js:183:24

React will try to recreate this component tree from scratch using the error boundary you provided, ErrorBoundaryHandler.
```

I am doing a similar conditional render in the layout of the home page and it is not giving any error. I am not able to understand the error stack also.

What is causing the issue and how to fix it?

### Update

If it helps, using `redirect('/')` from `next/navigation` fixes the issue but I get below mentioned error in the browser:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: NEXT_REDIRECT
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue using next.js 14

I was conditionally redirecting in profile page.
I was getting the same error as you.

```
export default async function Profile() {
    const user = await getUser();
    if (!user) return redirect("/login");

    return (
        <main className="container w-full mx-auto">
            ..profile
        </main>
    );
}
```

Solved the issue somehow when I removed the suspense boundary from my root layout.

My root layout had this line:

```
<Suspense fallback="Loading">{children}</Suspense>
```

and removing the Suspense resolved the error for me. Hope this helps to anyone else having the same issue.

Note:
As seen in the [documentation](https://nextjs.org/docs/app/api-reference/functions/redirect#server-component), when used in a server component, redirect throws a NEXT_REDIRECT exception to handle redirects so don't wrap it in try catch.